# How to define if component nested to itself in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I try to create custom Angular component for navigation menu. This menu can be nested, so it is 2nd level menu. Here is how it looks:

**app.component.html**

```html
<nav-menu>
  <nav-menu-item>Section 1</nav-menu-item>
  <nav-menu-item>Section 2
    <nav-menu>
      <nav-menu-item>Subsection 2.1</nav-menu-item>
      <nav-menu-item>Subsection 2.2</nav-menu-item>
      <nav-menu-item>Subsection 2.3</nav-menu-item>
    </nav-menu>
  </nav-menu-item>
  <nav-menu-item>Section 3</nav-menu-item>    
</nav-menu>
```

I have created two components.

**menu.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-menu',
  template: '<ng-content select="nav-menu-item"></ng-content>',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') class = 'nav-menu';
}
```

**menu-item.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-menu-item',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-item.component.css']
})
export class MenuItemComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') class = 'nav-menu-item';
}
```

The problem is that the sub-menu must have different styles. So I have to differ if menu item is nested (2nd level) or not. I can fix this problem in CSS with such selector `.nav-item .nav-item {}`, but it would be better to have different CSS classes for 1st and 2nd level of menu item.

How to define if component nested to itself?

[Example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-nav-menu)

Comment: you can add a @Input level() and your component was < nav-menu-item [level]="0" > or < nav-menu-item [level]="1" >

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the need to specify the level of navigation using input parameters makes the component more complicated. I found another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with dependency injection parameters `@Optional` and `@SkipSelf`. If the menu has the same menu among the ancestors, then this menu is nested. Same for menu items.

```
constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentMenu: MenuComponent) {
  if (parentMenu) {
    this.class = 'nav-submenu';
  }
}
```

[Updated Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-nav-menu-fixed)

Comment: I tried that but was getting cyclic dependency, good to know about SkipSelf.

Answer (score 2):

You can piece through with >>>

```
:host >>> nav-menu-item
```

Should allow you to style the child

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-nav-menu-3v4iat

Comment: Maybe I incorrectly formulated a question, but nested menu should also have different behaviour, so your solution will not work for this case.